# How can I stop table headers from auto adjusting after filtering

Tags: html, jquery

the main issue here is that when I filter my table, the headers are like moving to the left. For what I can see, it's happeing when I'm searching for a small string on the first column, seems like when searching for a long string it doesn't happen.
Seems like the table headers are addapting to the new column size, I'm trying to keep the headers fixed or something but no luck yet.

Adding some images and my code

[Here is the original table before filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBRBe.png)

[Here are the headers after filtering, I'm trying no to show any info sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQaig.png)

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>


<!-- foo Region header -->
<div id="fooRegionAccordion"
    class="ui-accordion-header toggle-button uppercase-text no-border-top"
    data-toggle-content="contentSpaceUsageAccordion">
    <a href=""><span
        class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon opened-accordion-icon"></span>
        foo Regions </a>
</div>

<!-- foo Region body -->
<div id="" class="col-sm-12 margin-left-10">

    <div id="" class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
        <label class="no-margin no-padding margin-left-20"> FILTER BY
            NAME/CODE </label>
    </div>
    
    <div id="fooRegionContainer" class="col-sm-12 no-padding margin-bottom-container">
        <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
            <div>
                <input id="fooRegionSearch" class="input-column input-default" type="text"
                    name="divisonRegionSearch" maxlength="40" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="button" id="search" value="SEARCH"
                class="btn btn-default uppercase-text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="button" id="reset" value="RESET"
                class="btn btn-default uppercase-text">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="regionTableContainer" class="col-sm-12 no-padding margin-top-container">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover monitoring-table"
            id="fooRegionTable">
            <thead class="thead-dark no-padding">
                <tr>
                    <th class="left-align-text" scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th class="left-align-text" scope="col">Code</th>
                    <th class="left-align-text" scope="col">Country</th>
                    <th class="center-align-text" scope="col">Region</th>
                    <th class="center-align-text" scope="col">Sub-Region</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="foos" items="${foos}">
                    <tr id="fooRegionInformation" class="mtrow">
                        <th class=" left-align-text no-padding fooName" scope="row">${foos.name}</th>

                        <td class="left-align-text no-padding fooCode">${foos.code}</td>

                        <td class="left-align-text no-padding">${foos.country}</td>

                        <td class="center-align-text no-padding">${foos.region}</td>

                        <td class="center-align-text no-padding">${foos.subregion}</td>

                    </tr>

                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#fooRegionSearch').on('keydown keypress', (function(e) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
            $("#search").click();
        }
    }));

    $("#search").click(function() { 
        var value = $("#fooRegionSearch").val();
        var rows = $("#fooRegionTable").find("tr");
        var firstRow = $("tr:first");
        rows.hide();
        rows.filter((_, row) => $(row).find('.fooName, .fooCode').filter(":contains('"+ value.toUpperCase() +"')").length
        ).show(); 
        firstRow.show();
    });

    $("#reset").click(function() {
        var value = $("#fooRegionSearch").val();
        var rows = $("#fooRegionTable").find("tr");
        $('#fooRegionSearch').val('');
        rows.show();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the table-layout: fixed; worked. I know it's a pretty easy question and fix but I'm leaving it in case anyone ends up here